# Can R7RS-small implementations allow only one define-library per file?

Tags: scheme, language-lawyer, r7rs

Are compliant R7RS-small implementations allowed to impose a restriction on the number of `define-library` per file? Some R7RS-small implementations such as Guile 3.0.7 only allow one `define-library` per file. Is this a deviation from the standard, or is it allowed by R7RS-small?

Answer (score 0):

In R7RS `define-library` is just a form, similar to `library` in R6RS. I don't see any allowances in either case that conforming implementations may constrain a file to contain only one such form.

But the Guile documentation has something to say on the matter. In [7.7 R7RS Support](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/guile.html#R7RS-Support):

> Happily, the syntax for R7RS modules was chosen to be compatible with R6RS, and so Guile’s documentation there applies.

In [7.7.1 Incompatibilities with the R7RS](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/guile.html#R7RS-Incompatibilities):

> As the R7RS is a much less ambitious standard than the R6RS (see Guile and Scheme), it is very easy for Guile to support. As such, Guile is a fully conforming implementation of R7RS, with the exception of the occasional bug and a couple of unimplemented features....

Then in [7.6.1 Incompatibilities with the R6RS](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/guile.html#R6RS-Incompatibilities)

> Multiple `library` forms in one file are not yet supported. This is because the expansion of `library` sets the current module, but does not restore it. This is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think they can (and, perhaps, should).

If you look at the formal syntax & semantics in [`r7rs.pdf`](https://small.r7rs.org/attachment/r7rs.pdf) then

- A program is one or more import declarations followed by one or more commands or definitions.  Commands and definitions *don't* include `define-library`.
- A library is *exactly one* `define-library` form.

So from that you can conclude that a program doesn't include `define-library` forms, and a library includes exactly one such form.

Now that document *doesn't* say how all this maps into files at all, so it's up to the implementation to define that.  I think it would be perfectly possible for an implementation to say that the mapping of files to library files should be 1-1, so any given library file contains exactly one library.  It would also be possible to have files which contained mixtures of a program and one or more libraries, of course.

In the case where libraries are in their own files (which is obviously the more interesting case in terms of allowing reuse) something has to turn a library name into a file.  And that would make it reasonably natural to put exactly one library in each file.

---

If it was me, I'd allow files which contain a mixture of a program and one or more libraries directly present, but for files which were just libraries I'd allow just one in each file.