How to make the variable loaded in one loaded file available in Scheme?
I have the following directory structure (minimal demo):
main.scm
(load "regex_utils.scm")
(displayln "test")
...

regex_utils.scm
(load "utils.scm")
... ; load many other lib files

utils.scm
(define (displayln x)
  (newline)
  (display x))

But when running scheme < main.scm it will throw error ";Unbound variable: displayln". How to make displayln available in regex_utils.scm also available in main.scm?
It seems to be related with environment which is used in MIT 6.5151 code base. But I don't know how to make 2 files sharing one environment since the-environment can be only called in a top-level environment. (I only read Software Design for Flexibility up to section 2.2, so this paragraph may have some errors.)

Following the comment, I tried:
main.scm (hinted by this reddit comment and R7RS)
(find-scheme-libraries! ".")
,(import (regex single-assert-grep=))

regex_utils.scm (Here "software/sdf" codes see this repo. This is from Software Design for Flexibility (SDF) related MIT 6.5151 course code base and it is a bit heavy work to rewrite them in define-library.)
(find-scheme-libraries! ".")
,(import (common displayln))
(define-library (regex single-assert-grep=)
  (export single-assert-grep=)
  (include 
            "../../software/sdf/manager/load.scm"
            "../../software/sdf/common/testing.scm"
            "../../software/sdf/regular-expressions/test-regexp.scm")
  (begin
    ;; based on ../software/sdf/common/testing.scm and test-regexp.scm.
    (define (single-assert-grep= expected pattern)
      (assert (equal*? expected
                    (r:grep pattern tests-file)))))
  )

utils.scm
(define-library (common displayln)
  (export displayln check_all_conds)
  (begin
    (define (displayln x)
      (newline)
      (display x))
    (define (check_all_conds condition lst)
      (assert (fold 
                (lambda (x y) (and x y)) 
                #t 
                (map condition lst))))))

scheme < main.scm will output
...
(find-scheme-libraries! ".")
;Registering library (common displayln) from "/home/czg_arch/SICP_SDF/SDF_exercises/chapter_2/./utils.scm"... done
;Unspecified return value

1 ]=> ,(import (regex single-assert-grep=))
;Error: Unregistered import libraries: ((regex single-assert-grep=))
;Unspecified return value


It seems that the lib (common utils) is already registered but only register one lib without (regex single-assert-grep=).

Then I tried scheme < regex_utils.scm it will throw (all-tests is defined in "../../software/sdf/common/testing.scm"):
1 ]=> ,(import (common displayln))
;Warning: Library exports refer to unbound identifiers: (displayln check_all_conds)
;Loading "./utils.scm"... done
;Warning: Library exports refer to unbound identifiers: (displayln check_all_conds)
;Error: Unbound variable: x
;Unspecified return value
...
;Definition may not be used as an expression: #[defn-item 12 all-tests #[expr-item 13]]

If I commented out (include ... ), then scheme < regex_utils.scm will throw ";Definition may not be used as an expression: #[defn-item 12 single-assert-grep= #[expr-item 13]]".


Then how to correctly use define-library in the above situation?

workaround used at first before posting this question:
put the following code at the top of each code needing lib (how to use manage see this)
(load "../software/sdf/manager/load")
(manage 'new 'regular-expressions)
(load "../software/sdf/common/testing.scm")
(load "../software/sdf/regular-expressions/test-regexp.scm")
(load "utils.scm")
(load "regex_utils.scm")


MIT Scheme is supposed to support R7RS style modules. I'd use them instead of load.

@Shawn I tried searching "module" in https://small.r7rs.org/attachment/r7rs.pdf but failed. Do you mean define-library https://stackoverflow.com/a/70420315/21294350? Please see my edited post where I encountered one new small problem.

@Shawn I tried to follow https://small.r7rs.org/attachment/r7rs.pdf "5.6.2. Library example" (example grid) since I have more than one functions in the lib. But it doesn't export grid and even doesn't define it. I tried your 2nd comment for (common displayln) but failed. I updated my post with the more detailed description about my code env. Could you give one more simple example to show how to use this feature?

For starters the library is named (regex) but you try to import (regex utils)

Also MIT scheme doesn't seem to have a top-level import. Hmm. Maybe it's not as R7RS-compliant as it claims.

Apparently you have to use ,(import (foo)) from the REPL. Note the leading comma.

@Shawn (The following number is to correspond to the above comment list.) 1. Sorry. That's one typo. I have fixed it just now. 2. If so, then is there one workaround? 3. ,... seems to be used in quasiquote normally. What does it do here? If define-library is not easy to be used in the above situation, I give one straightforward workaround used at first in the edited post although not elegant.

See https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/stable/mit-scheme-user/REPL-Escapes.html
